# Настройка доступа к БД

Tags: mysql

Привет .

Цель - создать 2 базы данных. Скачал клиент - `xampp` и установил в 2 разных папки. По отдельности они работают.

Запускаю их вместе (см. скрин). В файле my.ini поменял порт:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3307
```

[image]

Теперь запускаю консоль  и получаю доступ mysql:

```
C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot
```

и

```
C:/xampp2/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot
```

Теперь пробую посмотреть данные БД, и они идентичны. Как так? Что поменять, чтобы не использовалась одна БД?

**Обновление**

В настройке прописано:

```
basedir = "C:/xampp2/mysql"   
tmpdir = "C:/xampp2/tmp"   
datadir = "C:/xampp2/mysql/data"
```

Для 1 сервера путь другой...

Comment: Не мне ли только кажется, что вам надо два mysql инстанса поднять?

Comment: Хочу иметь 2 сервера, чтобы протестировать возможность репликации.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши "два сервера" используют один и тот же каталог для хранения файлов  базы данных. Соответственно и таблицы/базы одни и те же.

**Обновление**

Я понял, кажется. Они берут один и тот же файл конфига. Поэтому нужно его задать явно с помощью аргумента `--defaults-file=имя-файла`.

Comment: Почему? В настройке прописано: 

basedir = "C:/xampp2/mysql" 

tmpdir = "C:/xampp2/tmp" 

datadir = "C:/xampp2/mysql/data" 

Для 1 сервера путь другой...

Comment: Я, к сожалению (или к радости своей?), не телепат и не вижу всего, что творится в Ваших конфигах.

Comment: Может, подскажите атрибуты, которые также отвечают за путя? У меня стандартный конфиг, только  скачаный...